# JLabel with HTML inline image

Tags: java, html, jlabel, inline-images

I'm trying to create a JLabel with mixed content: text and inline images.
The component later should contain dynamically count of images and text (with dynamically order).

My first steps: Create an JLabel like follows:

```
JLabel label = new JLabel("<html>wow! <img src="data:image/png;base64,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"></html>");
```

If I add the label to a component, it looks like this:

[image]

-> missing image!

But if I put the html code from the label inside an .html file and open it with chrome, it looks good:
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Regards, 
Florian

Answer (score 2):

Try to add your image with the setIcon() method of Jlabel :

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(YOUR_PATH); 
JLabel thumb = new JLabel();
thumb.setIcon(icon);
```

By replacing YOUR_PATH by the absolute oath of your image.
Hope it will help !

EDIT : (If you really want to use html image tag, Java may encounter some difficulties in finding your image : use this to have a correct path usable by your program (supposing your image is in the current directory) :

```
URL url = HTMLLabel.class.getResource( "/image.png" );
```

Then access your image like this :

```
"...<img src =" + url + "/> ..."
```

Comment: the original reply is not helpful, but the edit is great